# Check every condition in Python if else even if one evaluates to true

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there a way in Python to continue checking conditions of an if else statement if one evaluates to true? Here's my code:

```
status = True

  if pass_len(S) == False:
    print ('Password must be at least 6 characters long')
    status = False
  elif pass_upper(S) == False:
    print('Password must include upper case letters')
    status = False
  elif pass_lower(S) == False:
    print('Password must include lower case letters')
    status = False
  elif pass_nums(S) == False:
    print('Password must include digits.')
    status = False
  else:
    status = True

  return status
```

For example, if the password doesn't have an uppercase character or numbers, I'd like to print both messages, instead of just "Password must include upper case letters" and it ending right there. I tried getting around this by taking return out of each statement, but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: yes get rid of the elif...

Comment: You don't need the last `else: status = True`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `elif`, using `if` will make sure the the condition is checked. `elif` will only be checked when the `if` statement evaluates to `False`

```
In [40]: foo = 3

In [41]: if foo == 3:
   ....:     print (foo)
   ....: if foo != 4:    
   ....:     print ("checked too")
   ....:     
3
checked too
```

`status = True` sets status to `True` already so just `return status` no need for an `else`

Comment: As a point of curiosity, I'd love to see this implemented with bitwise operations (e.g. `finalflags = run_all_the_tests(0)` where each test sets one bit). I'll probably throw something together as an exercise in a few hours.

Comment: @AdamSmith, That sounds interesting! I'd love to see it if you try something.

Comment: @JoseMagana I'll write it up as an answer when I'm done

Answer (score 6):

An alternate way to do this that is a bit shorter and also gives you a list of which errors triggered is a list comprehension:

```python
errors = [message for (has_error, message) in (
    (not pass_len(S), 'Password must be at least 6 characters long'),
    (not pass_upper(S), 'Password must include upper case letters'),
    (not pass_lower(S), 'Password must include lower case letters'),
    (not pass_nums(S), 'Password must include digits.'),
    ) if has_error]
```

Comment: Ooh I really like this.

Comment: That's awesome. I haven't learned this yet. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You may refactor that into `RULES = [(pass_len, '...'), (pass_upper, '...'), ...]; errors = [message for test, message in RULES if not test(S)]`

Comment: @Suor only if all future rules will operate on the one parameter S

Answer (score 1):

Stealing viciously from @JasonS's excellent answer, here's the bit-twiddling approach I mentioned in a comment.

```
# :: all functions look just like this one! ::
import functools, operator

def pass_len(password, length=6):
    try:
        if len(password) < length:
            return 0b0001
        else:
            return 0
    except Exception as e:
        return 0b0001
# pass_upper returns 0b0010 or 0
# pass_lower returns 0b0100 or 0
# pass_nums  returns 0b1000 or 0

def password_validate(password):
    conditions = [pass_len, pass_upper, pass_lower, pass_nums]
    result = functools.reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda x: x(password), conditions))
    errors = [message for (bitflag, message) in (
        (0b0001, 'Password must be at least 6 characters long'),
        (0b0010, 'Password must include upper case letters'),
        (0b0100, 'Password must include lower case letters'),
        (0b1000, 'Password must include digits.')
        ) if result & bitflag]
    for error in errors:
        print(error)
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> password_validate("hunter12")
Password must include upper case letters
>>> password_validate("HUNTER")
Password must include lower case letters
Password must include digits.
>>> password_validate('')
Password must be at least 6 characters long
Password must include upper case letters
Password must include lower case letters
Password must include digits.
```

You can DRY this off further by doing:

```
def password_validator(bitflag):
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapped_f(*args):
            return bitflag if f(*args) else 0
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap

@password_validator(0b0001)
def pass_len(password, length=6):
    return len(password) < length
@password_validator(0b0010)
def pass_upper(password):
    return password.lower() == password
@password_validator(0b0100)
def pass_lower(password):
    return password.upper() == password
@password_validator(0b1000)
def pass_num(password):
    return any(num in password for num in '0123456789')

def password_validate(password):
    # this function is identical to the one above
```

Comment: Wow, a really unique approach to this problem! I'm pretty new to computer science and I'm wondering: Are bitwise operations are common usage in software engineering industry? This looks pretty cool.

Comment: @JoseMagana see my edit for a much DRYer way to do this using decorators. Bitwise operations are usually much faster, but are otherwise much less readable. Approach them like you would any other optimization -- early optimization is the devil, but once you've profiled your code and noticed "Oh hey this is my bottleneck," then expect to spend AT LEAST as much time documenting and explaining your bitwise operations as the time you expect to gain out of it for the next several months :)

Comment: @JoseMagana That said, since my code isn't actually doing any reasonable work with the bitflags, it's probably even a bit slower than standard conditionals. Note that if you use Jason's code, he calls each function once, while when you call mine I call each function once and then have to check its output later. That's slower.

Comment: why on earth "if len(password) < length" would throw an exception ... ?

Comment: @kmonsoor if you pass it any object that doesn't have a `__len__` magic method defined? For instance a number. Or in fact any object that for some poorly-thought-out reason its `__len__` function returns something that isn't orderable with a number. Or I suppose if you toss a similarly unorderable number into the `length` kwarg (`"Hello World" < [1,2,3,4]` probably throws a `TypeError`)