# Returning all the 'if conditions values' in a separate column

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, return-value

I have a data frame, on which I am applying 'if' condition to return certain vales. I want to create a new column which will have those values but in cases where multiple conditions are satisfied, I want all the 'return' values in that column

For the following dataframe, for instance

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'Status':('reliable','non-reliable','reliable','non-reliable','reliable','reliable','non-reliable'),
                       'Gender': ('M','M','F','M','F','M','F'),
                       'Domain': ('Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes'),
                       'Paid': ('Paid','Paid','Paid','Not Paid','Paid','Not Paid','Paid')
        })
```

Sample conditions are as follows. For instance if 'Status is reliable and Gender is F', the new column should have both the return value 'reliable True' and 'F True'

```
def sample_column(row):
    if ((row['Status'] == 'reliable')):
        return 'reliable True'
    if ((row['Gender'] == 'F')):
        return 'F True'
    if ((row['Domain'] == 'Yes')):
        return 'Doamin True'
```

Finally building the column

```
sample = sample.assign(True_cases = sample.apply(sample_column,axis=1))
```

I found one sample solution here (but I am not able to replicate): [Check every condition in Python if else even if one evaluates to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211924/check-every-condition-in-python-if-else-even-if-one-evaluates-to-true)

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be generate a mask, and then concat the result on a row by row selection:

```
conds = {
    'Status': 'reliable',
    'Gender': 'M',
    'Domain': 'Yes',
    'Paid': 'Paid'
}
mask = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(sample)
for c in mask.columns:
    mask[c] = sample[c] == conds[c]

sample['True Column'] = [
    ' '.join([
            '{} True'.format(s) for s in  sample.loc[i, mask.loc[i]]
    ]) for i in sample.index
]
```

I used a relatively clumsy double-for loop here, but you can wrap the string formatting in a function to get better performance. Results would be :

```
  Domain Gender      Paid        Status  \
0    Yes      M      Paid      reliable   
1     No      M      Paid  non-reliable   
2    Yes      F      Paid      reliable   
3     No      M  Not Paid  non-reliable   
4    Yes      F      Paid      reliable   
5     No      M  Not Paid      reliable   
6    Yes      F      Paid  non-reliable   

                               True Column  
0  Yes True M True Paid True reliable True  
1                         M True Paid True  
2         Yes True Paid True reliable True  
3                                   M True  
4         Yes True Paid True reliable True  
5                     M True reliable True  
6                       Yes True Paid True
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what would be the purpose for this, but it doesn't seem like Pandas would be the best tool for this output? IMHO if you are looking for long human-readable strings you shouldn't try to fit it into a DataFrame.

Regardless, if the formatting is variable, it can be done as an extension of my original solution, by passing a custom formatting function:

```
conds = {
    'Status': ('reliable', lambda s: 'The status is {}'.format(s)),
    'Gender': ('M', lambda s: 'The gender is {}'.format(s)),
    'Domain': ('Yes', lambda s: 'Hello'),
    'Paid': ('Paid', lambda s: 'The bill has been settled')
}
mask = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(sample)
for c in mask.columns:
    mask[c] = sample[c] == conds[c][0]

sample['True Column'] = [
    ' '.join([
            conds[c][1](s) for c, s in sample.loc[i, mask.loc[i]].iteritems()
    ]) for i in sample.index
]
```

Otherwise, you can use your function but just append each matched statement into a list and join it at the end:

```
def sample_column(row):
    ol = []
    if ((row['Status'] == 'reliable')):
        ol.append('reliable True')
    if ((row['Gender'] == 'F')):
        ol.append('F True')
    if ((row['Domain'] == 'Yes')):
        ol.append('Domain True')

    return ' '.join(ol)
sample['True Column'] = sample.apply(sample_column,axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this solution. This is indeed quite interesting. The reason why I was using 'if' function was because I could control the return statement. For instance 'reliable true' is just a sample output (so is F True). Ideally if status is reliable, I would like to return 'The individual is reliable' and if 'Gender is M' would like to return ' The individual is male' and if both conditions are valid the new column will have - 'The individual is reliable'  ' The individual is male'. Is that possible. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: Open another question and better scope out what exactly you want and what you have tried to get there so far. No one here likes changing goalposts and we like to give proper answers to proper questions, not guess at what you are thinking

Comment: What @ycx said is correct, and the question is improperly scoped. Regardless I edited my answer to reflect what you are asking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's `where` function and `&` to chain your conditions
See `np.where` in the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
sample = pd.DataFrame({'Status':('reliable','non-reliable','reliable','non-reliable','reliable','reliable','non-reliable'),
                       'Gender': ('M','M','F','M','F','M','F'),
                       'Domain': ('Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes'),
                       'Paid': ('Paid','Paid','Paid','Not Paid','Paid','Not Paid','Paid')
        })

import numpy as np
sample['True_Column'] = np.where( 
        (sample['Status']=='reliable') & 
        (sample['Gender']=='F') & 
        (sample['Domain']=='Yes'), 
        'True', 'False')

print (sample)
#         Status Gender Domain      Paid True_Column
#0      reliable      M    Yes      Paid       False
#1  non-reliable      M     No      Paid       False
#2      reliable      F    Yes      Paid        True
#3  non-reliable      M     No  Not Paid       False
#4      reliable      F    Yes      Paid        True
#5      reliable      M     No  Not Paid       False
#6  non-reliable      F    Yes      Paid       False
```

For more complex conditions, you can use `np.select`.
I am not exactly sure how your logic to determine `F True`, `reliable True` and `Domain True` is exactly being done, so you have to be more specific in your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do'not want the new column to have just 'True' or 'False' value, I want the exact text which describes the condition which is met. I can build several if conditions to do that, but that would be a very lengthy code. First I test for one value then do combination of condtions

Comment: You have to write out what exactly is your conditions looking like in an `if elif else` structure, then I can best advise you on what to use to fulfill it

Comment: It could be like this     def sample_column(row):
    if ((row['Status'] == 'reliable')):
        return 'reliable True'
    elif ((row['Gender'] == 'F')):
        return 'F True'
    elif ((row['Domain'] == 'Yes')):
        return 'Doamin True' else return 'True'

Comment: I think @Mike https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809959/9757927 came up with the answer you required. Do let me know if that's what works for you

Comment: it has not completely solved the problem. As I want to have custom return statement. Also I want to give different return statement for cases where the Status is 'not-reliable'